# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' for Python

Tags: python, floating-point

I facing an error:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Not sure where is the error...headhache

```
inp_df = final_df.drop(final_df.columns[[4]], axis=1)
out_df = final_df.drop(final_df.columns[[0,1,2,3]], axis=1)
#
scaler = StandardScaler()
inp_df = scaler.fit_transform(inp_df)
#
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(inp_df, out_df, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

inp_df = final_df.drop(final_df.columns[[4]], axis=1)
out_df = final_df.drop(final_df.columns[[0,1,2,3]], axis=1)
#
scaler = StandardScaler()
inp_df = scaler.fit_transform(inp_df)
#
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(inp_df, out_df, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

print('Input Shape', (X_tr_arr.shape))
print('Output Shape', X_test.shape)

def weightInitialization(n_features):
    w = np.zeros((1,n_features))
    b = 0
    return w,b

def sigmoid_activation(result):
    final_result = 1/(1+np.exp(-result))
    return final_result


def model_optimize(w, b, X, Y):
    m = X.shape[0]
    
    #Prediction
    final_result = sigmoid_activation(np.dot(w,X.T)+b)
    Y_T = Y.T
    cost = (-1/m)*(np.sum((Y_T*np.log(final_result)) + ((1-Y_T)*(np.log(1-final_result)))))
    #
    
    #Gradient calculation
    dw = (1/m)*(np.dot(X.T, (final_result-Y.T).T))
    db = (1/m)*(np.sum(final_result-Y.T))
    
    grads = {"dw": dw, "db": db}
    
    return grads, cost

def model_predict(w, b, X, Y, learning_rate, no_iterations):
    costs = []
    for i in range(no_iterations):
        #
        grads, cost = model_optimize(w,b,X,Y)
        #
        dw = grads["dw"]
        db = grads["db"]
        #weight update
        w = w - (learning_rate * (dw.T))
        b = b - (learning_rate * db)
        #
        
        if (i % 100 == 0):
            costs.append(cost)
            #print("Cost after %i iteration is %f" %(i, cost))
    
    #final parameters
    coeff = {"w": w, "b": b}
    gradient = {"dw": dw, "db": db}
    
    return coeff, gradient, costs

def predict(final_pred, m):
    y_pred = np.zeros((1,m))
    for i in range(final_pred.shape[1]):
        if final_pred[0][i] > 0.5:
            y_pred[0][i] = 1
    return y_pred









#Get number of features
n_features = X_tr_arr.shape[1]
print('Number of Features', n_features)
w, b = weightInitialization(n_features)
#Gradient Descent
coeff, gradient, costs = model_predict(w, b, X_tr_arr, y_tr_arr, learning_rate=0.0001,no_iterations=4500)
#Final prediction
w = coeff["w"]
b = coeff["b"]
print('Optimized weights', w)
print('Optimized intercept',b)
#
final_train_pred = sigmoid_activation(np.dot(w,X_tr_arr.T)+b)
final_test_pred = sigmoid_activation(np.dot(w,X_ts_arr.T)+b)
#
m_tr =  X_tr_arr.shape[0]
m_ts =  X_ts_arr.shape[0]
#
y_tr_pred = predict(final_train_pred, m_tr)
print('Training Accuracy',accuracy_score(y_tr_pred.T, y_tr_arr))
#
y_ts_pred = predict(final_test_pred, m_ts)
print('Test Accuracy',accuracy_score(y_ts_pred.T, y_ts_arr))
```

I am using python notebook

('Number of Features', 4L)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-110-2e390b463717> in <module>()
      4 w, b = weightInitialization(n_features)
      5 #Gradient Descent
----> 6 coeff, gradient, costs = model_predict(w, b, X_tr_arr, y_tr_arr, learning_rate=0.0001,no_iterations=4500)
      7 #Final prediction
      8 w = coeff["w"]

<ipython-input-107-f28af5fdf927> in model_predict(w, b, X, Y, learning_rate, no_iterations)
      3     for i in range(no_iterations):
      4         #
----> 5         grads, cost = model_optimize(w,b,X,Y)
      6         #
      7         dw = grads["dw"]

<ipython-input-106-d37a364dc23d> in model_optimize(w, b, X, Y)
      5     final_result = sigmoid_activation(np.dot(w,X.T)+b)
      6     Y_T = Y.T
----> 7     cost = (-1/m)*(np.sum((Y_T*np.log(final_result)) + ((1-Y_T)*(np.log(1-final_result)))))
      8     #
      9 

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Comment: `Y_T` probably isn't what you think it is. Without a [mcve] I don't know what you think it is, and I don't know what it is instead. My guess is that it is a string or a vector of strings.

Comment: I think that `Y_T*np.log(final_result)` is the subexpression in the line which the traceback shows which is the thing which actually throws the error. You would have to *trace* back through the traceback to see where that value ultimately comes from in your code.

Comment: @JohnColeman, Yes, got your meaning. I had edited my question. I quite long. `#Prediction
    final_result = sigmoid_activation(np.dot(w,X.T)+b)
    Y_T = Y.T
    cost = (-1/m)*(np.sum((Y_T*np.log(final_result)) + ((1-Y_T)*(np.log(1-final_result)))))`